# How to insert a variable in count() function?

Tags: php, sql, count

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("select Count(id='$id') As Total from topics");
```

The above code is only working if we put count(id) but i want to get count of selected variable. How to insert `id='$id'` in count function it is not working please help related this.

Comment: "mysql_query" so i think it's mysql without pdo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a where clause in your sql query, which I believe would look like this:

```
select count(id) As Total from topics where id='$id'
```

note: depending on what type of column you have for your id field, you might need to drop the single quotes.

---

**Warning**

your code is vulnerable to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) you need to escape all `get`, `post` and `request` and the better approach will be using [Prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

**Good Read**

1. [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
2. [**Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202218/1723893)

### **Note**

1. The entire **`ext/mysql`** PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. So use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`

**Good read**

1. [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#comment19236631_13944958.)
2. [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)
3. [Pdo Tutorial For Beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear but perhaps you're looking for `COUNT CASE WHEN id = $id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` (you can even skip the `ELSE 0` part I believe).

Answer (score 0):

`$id` get values of `$_GET['id']`

if you want other data, use `$id="your data here"`

Answer (score 0):

What actually are you trying to do is pretty unclear in the Question.
But if you are trying to count the number of rows then simple `select count(*) as Total where {your condition} from table` will will do for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`" . $id . "`) AS `Total` FROM `Topics`");
```

But do note that this isn't very secure since it will be vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Count can be used as below

```
<?php
$shoes=array("nike","puma","lancer");
echo count($shoes);
?>
```

Read the documentation in the PHP manual on Count.For inserting id in count:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM clients'); 
$count = mysql_result($result,0); 
echo $count;
```